Problem loading file path (image) from room with coil
I have an image taken from CameraX.
I wanted to save my image to room but too much problem. So i decided to save my image to cacheDir with a unique name and then save the path to room.
The problem is when i'm fetching the data, and insert it into AsyncImage from coil, it doesn't load anything.
Here is my code.
Thank's for your response !
ViewModel
try {
    val cacheFile = File(context.cacheDir, "space_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png")

    Log.i("cachedfile", cacheFile.toString())

    val outPutStream = FileOutputStream(cacheFile)

    outPutStream.flush()

    outPutStream.close()

    addSpaceRepository.insertSpace(
        space = Space(
            id = "space_".plus(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()),
            name = _uiState.value.spaceName.trim(),
            color = _uiState.value.spaceColor.toArgb(),
            iconName = _uiState.value.spaceIcon?.name ?: Icons.Rounded.Kitchen.name,
            fileImageCache = cacheFile.path.toString()
        )
    )
} catch (e: Throwable) {
    Log.e("erreur load file", "Cause : ${e.localizedMessage}")
}

ScreenComposable
cacheFilePath?.let {
    AsyncImage(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
            .data(File(it))
            .build(),
        contentDescription = "Image Space"

    )
}

TakePhoto
controller.takePicture(
    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
    object : OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            super.onCaptureSuccess(image)

            val matrix = Matrix().apply {
                postRotate(image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat())
            }

            val rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                image.toBitmap(),
                0,
                0,
                image.width,
                image.height,
                matrix,
                true
            )

            onPhotoTaken(rotatedBitmap)
        }

        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
            super.onError(exception)

            Log.e("Camera launch", "Couldn't take photo: ", exception)
        }
    }
)

EDIT
Adding bitmap.compress in viewModel function does the job (How can i forgot to do that...)
_uiState.value.spaceBitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outPutStream)

But the problem is that i can't save to PNG, it crash.
How can i do that ?

Does cacheFilePath have the value that you expect, when you are in that composable?

i don't uderstand something, okay i have created a file url, but where is stored my image ?? My take(photo) function is just capturing the imageProxy, then register it as a bitmap but i don't see a function where i save the image on a specific file.

I managed to solve the problem, now i can't save file to PNG, only JPEG. If i try to do so, it crash.
How can i do that ?

That would be another question. If you found a solution for this question, you can write an answer yourself so others that might stumble upon this question in the future can benefit from it.

Don't forget to add compress into outPutStream function when saving photo to local
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outPutStream)

